# Difference between render :action and render :template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rendering

What is the difference between `render :action => "new"` and `render :template => "users/new"`? I have heard that rendering template, we can use for views from other controllers. Is that it or is there any difference in rendering layout also between the two? For render :template, is it neccessary to have an action defined or is the view page itself enough?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

There is no difference.
 `render :template => 'some/thing'` is the same as just `render 'some/thing'`, as well as the same as `render :action => 'thing'` if we are in the `some` controller.

From [Ruby On Rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html);

```
render :edit
render :action => :edit
render 'edit'
render 'edit.html.erb'
render :action => 'edit'
render :action => 'edit.html.erb'
render 'books/edit'
render 'books/edit.html.erb'
render :template => 'books/edit'
render :template => 'books/edit.html.erb'
render '/path/to/rails/app/views/books/edit'
render '/path/to/rails/app/views/books/edit.html.erb'
render :file => '/path/to/rails/app/views/books/edit'
render :file => '/path/to/rails/app/views/books/edit.html.erb'
```

Answer (score 5):

Previously, calling render `"foo/bar"` in a controller action was equivalent to `render file: "foo/bar"`. In Rails 4.2, this has been changed to mean `render template: "foo/bar"` instead. If you need to render a file, please change your code to use the explicit form (`render file: "foo/bar"`) instead.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/4_2_release_notes.html#render-with-a-string-argument

Answer (score 0):

```
 render :action => 'some_controller_action', :layout => 'some_layout_in_layout_folder'
```

will render the view of that controller action and apply the asset settings (`javascript`, `CSS`) of the `some_layout_in_layout_folder` layout.

If you  write this in a controller action, it will use the styling of the specified layout in conjunction with any layout defined at the beginning of the class, if any