# rails render is not working in create action

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my controller I coded like this

```
 class CompanyUploadRequestsController < ApiController
  def index
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { render action: "index" }
    end
  end

  def create
    puts params
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { render action: "index" }
    end
  end

  def new
  end

end
```

and in my view `new.html.haml` file

```
- page_title("Upload Company")
%h1 Upload Company
%hr
#upload-form
  = simple_form_for(@company_upload, :as => :company_update, :url => company_upload_requests_path(@company_upload), :html => { :class => 'file-style'}) do |f|
    = f.error_notification

    .form-inputs
      = f.input :requestname, :label => false, :id => "request_name_input"
      = f.input :file,:as => :file, :label => false, :id => "file_select_input"

    .form-actions
      != link_to 'Cancel', company_upload_requests_path, :class => 'btn'
      = f.button :submit, 'Upload', :class => 'btn-primary'
```

In my `index.html.haml` file I have this

```
- page_title("Upload Company")
%h1 Company index
= link_to("Upload File", new_company_upload_request_path, :class => "btn btn-primary pull-right")
```

The problem is when I click upload button its not render to index page from create

Here I got the log like this

```
Processing by CompanyUploadRequestsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"?", "authenticity_token"=>"oygIP62E4GHefhN9OnvB3sKhddIb4CN/izfvF5GQtuI=", "company_update"=>{"requestname"=>""}, "commit"=>"Upload"}
  Rendered company_upload_requests/create.html.haml within layouts/application (9.8ms)
```

How can I render to index action and view index file content.

Comment: Try changing your render to redirect_to in your create method.

Comment: just wondering, why is it that you don't want to redirect back to index page after create action finish ? `redirect_to company_upload_requests_path`

Answer (score 1):

Use like this.

```
def index
   @company_uploads = ModelName.all
   respond_to do |format|
     format.html 
   end
end
```

No need to render index action in index response.

```
def create
  puts params
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { render "index" }
  end
end
```

Comment: Normal index action is working or not..?
for index action you need instance variable (like an array) to fetch records before respond

Comment: yeah Normal index action is working. I tried lot of method from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5045222/difference-between-render-action-and-render-template

Comment: For index action we need collection of records to show in index page.

Answer (score 0):

Change the `render` in your create method to `redirect_to`

```
def create
    puts params
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to action: "index" }
    end
  end
```

For more explanation on `render` vs `redirect_to`, see this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17236122/what-is-the-difference-between-link-to-redirect-to-and-render) Question or [this.](http://blog.markusproject.org/?p=3313)