# Ruby on Rails - Difference between Render and render action:

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, action, render

I'm having trouble understanding the difference between 'render' and 'render action:' in Ruby on Rails. I cannot find the answer to this.

```
render 'edit'
render action: :edit
```

Usually, edit is a RESTful method in a controller. When render 'edit' is called, the controller looks for a corresponding view file named edit.html.erb.

My initial guess is that both of these do the same thing. My question is what is the difference, if any between render 'action' and render action: 'action'? Is there any difference in performance speed? Is any convention favored over the other?

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between render :action and render :template](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5045222/difference-between-render-action-and-render-template)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From another SO answer: [Difference between render :action and render :template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5045222/difference-between-render-action-and-render-template/5045300#5045300)

and [Ruby on Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#wrapping-it-up):

```
render :edit
render action: :edit
render "edit"
render "edit.html.erb"
render action: "edit"
render action: "edit.html.erb"
render "books/edit"
render "books/edit.html.erb"
render template: "books/edit"
render template: "books/edit.html.erb"
render "/path/to/rails/app/views/books/edit"
render "/path/to/rails/app/views/books/edit.html.erb"
render file: "/path/to/rails/app/views/books/edit"
render file: "/path/to/rails/app/views/books/edit.html.erb"
```

are all the same, no difference.

Comment: That's what I figured. I needed to confirm that though. Thanks for your help

Comment: I'd go with the symbol, as you mentioned in @sircapsalot's answer

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure `render 'edit'` is just an attempt to save typability.

```
render 'edit'
```

Is just a synonym to:

```
render action: :edit
```

> Is there any difference in performance speed?

If there is, it would be minuscule and probably favoring the `action: :edit` since a string to symbol might take longer

Comment: That case, probably better to use render :edit, because symbols are more efficient than strings. It's also probably best to write as little as possible.