# Creating a dynamic root route in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a rails app where I am wanting to make the landing page dynamic so that every time the user goes to it it changes.

I have cafe's in my app, and each cafe has its own show page. I want each show page to be dynamic. The url's are based off of the cafe's id, so I figured I'd have to use those IDs as the focal point for creating the dynamic work i'm looking for.

In my cafe's controller I have

```
class CafesController < ApplicationController
  def root
    array = Cafe.pluck(:id)

    array.sample
  end
end
```

in my routes file I have

```
root 'cafes#root'
```

The error I'm getting is

```
`CafesController#root is missing a template for this request format and variant. `
```

Would anyone know what I am missing with this one? Much appreciated.

Comment: Error message says that the corresponding template for `CafesController#root` is missing. Try setting up view `app/views/cafes/root.html.erb` in order for `rails` to render it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I image you could do something like:

```
class CafeController < ApplicationController 
  def root
    redirect_to Cafe.all.sample
  end 
end
```

By the way, this approach has the benefits of letting you keep and use all your normal routes in the conventional manner.

Also, you might consider calling this action something a little more descriptive. Perhaps something like `random_cafe`. IMO, `root 'cafes#random_cafe'` is a bit more understandable.

Comment: I really like this idea, it works quite well for what I am trying to do. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

`missing a template error` because you have to specify a template to render, I'm imagining that `array.sample` will return something like `/cafes/firstsampe.html.erb` where `firstsampe.html.erb` persists inside cafes views folder so you can use it like this `redirect_to :template => array.sample`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Look at ways that you can render a template [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5045222/difference-between-render-action-and-render-template)

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any idea about what your data looks like, but there are two approaches you can take here:

1. Show a random cafe when the user hits your home page (root)
2. Redirect a user to a cafe's page randomly when they hit the home page

**In scenario 1:**

Controller:

```
class CafesController < ApplicationController
  def index
     @cafe = Cafe.order("RANDOM()").first
  end
end
```

Routing:

```
root 'cafes#index'
```

Views:

```
app/views/cafes/index.html.erb

<p><%= @cafe.name %></p>
```

**In scenario 2:**

Controller:

```
class CafesController < ApplicationController
  def index
     redirect_to cafe_path(Cafe.order("RANDOM()").first)
  end

  def show
    @cafe = Cafe.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

Routing:

```
root 'cafes#index'
resources :cafes, only: [:show]
```

Views:

```
app/views/cafes/show.html.erb

<p><%= @cafe.name %></p>
```